# Reload web page after form submission, hidden iframe

Tags: php, html, forms

I am making a simple image uploader.
I want it so:

1. An image is uploaded, it calls a php script.
2. The page is then refreshed

I am using a simple html form action. It does not refresh the web page after submission. To prevent the php script from overriding the web page, I put it in a hidden iframe.

I have never used javascript or ajax, so I am trying to avoid those solutions. This is a one-off for fun thing, so investing time into them isn't my goal.

```
 <body>
        <iframe name="votar" style="display:none;"></iframe>

        <p class="standard_text_big" style="text-align:center"> No Pin Limit Will Stop Us!</p>
        <p><form action="upload.php" method="post" target="votar" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="standard_text" style="text-align:center">
            Upload a File:
            <input type="file" name="the_file" id="fileToUpload">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Start Upload">
        </form>
        </p>

        <div class = "image_format">
        <picture class = "image_format">
            <div id="img_embed"></div>
            </div>
        </picture>    
    </body>
```

EDIT Solved:
Instead of doing this in the html page, I have removed the hidden iframe  so the php script does take over.
Then in the php script, after it executes, it sends you back to the html page.

Like so:

```
 <p class="standard_text_big" style="text-align:center"> No Pin Limit Will Stop Us!</p>
        <p><form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="standard_text" style="text-align:center">
            Upload a File:
            <input type="file" name="the_file" id="fileToUpload">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Start Upload">
        </form>
        </p>

        <div class = "image_format">
        <picture class = "image_format">
            <div id="img_embed"></div>
            </div>
        </picture>
```

Then in the php file:

```
 if (empty($errors)) {
        $didUpload = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $uploadPath);

        if ($didUpload) {
          echo "The file " . basename($fileName) . " has been uploaded";
          $command = escapeshellcmd('python3 /home/myfile.py');
          $output = shell_exec($command);
          echo $output;
          header("Location: https://www.google.com"); /* Redirect browser */
          exit();
```

Comment: "To prevent the php script from overriding the web page, I put it in a hidden iframe" <- why not just simply redirect back to the form instead?

Comment: Yup you are correct, I have basically done that now. I edited the post, it is solved now. Thank you.